# Django: activate user-stored language after login

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-i18n

I'm using Python 3.6 and Django 1.11. I'm using Django class-based auth views and custom user model. My users have their language stored in database. I would like to retrieve this language after every login and activate it.

I was hoping to do this through `user_logged_in` signal, but signals cannot affect response in any way, so this is not possible.

Another way is to override default auth views, which is something I wanted to avoid.

Is there any other way? Thank you.

Comment: You can still change the user language in signal through `translation.activate(usr_lan)`

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I can use `activate`, but the thing is that the request has i18n path ('/en/route/...' for instance). `LocaleMiddleware` prioritizes language from the URL, so this doesn't solve the problem. I would have to be able to redirect and that you cannot do from the signal.

Comment: Okay, How about extend `LocaleMiddleware` with your custom `CustomLocaleMiddleware` and `process_request` somehow get the lang and set ?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, @RajaSimon, I'll think about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, I went with a minimal auth view override. I found this better than custom language middleware, because middleware would add some overhead to every request, whereas this is executed only during login. I have overridden the `get_success_url` method because it is being called after user is logged in (that I need) and I didn't want to interfere with the login/authentication process itself, because that could potentially introduce a security hole in the future.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.urls import translate_url
from django.utils.translation import activate, LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY

# available languages should be obtained from settings.LANGUAGES
available_languages = [lang_code for (lang_code, lang_name) in settings.LANGUAGES]

class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    def get_success_url(self):
        url = super(CustomLoginView, self).get_success_url()
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated():
            language = user.get_setting('language')

            if language in available_languages:
                url = translate_url(url, language)
                activate(language)
                if hasattr(self.request, 'session'):
                    self.request.session[LANGUAGE_SESSION_KEY] = language

        return url
```